# Oauth2 Centralized SSO Provider with an external Resource Servers App is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have an OAuth2 Provider App (URL: http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize)  which will be accessed by multiple resource server apps (Rest Webservices). The idea here is to have all the permissions configured in the Centralized OAuth2 Provider and security for all the resource server apps should be validated against the OAuth2 Provider.

When I try to access http://localhost:8090/appA/xyz, I get a “Full Authentication Required” message.

Could you please let me know how App-A can read permissions from centralized OAuth2 provider?

My Authorization Server Configuration:

```
  @Configuration
  @RestController
  @EnableAuthorizationServer
  public class AuthorizationServer extends  AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(Principal user) {
    return user;
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

    //Start: Add App-A Protected Resources
    clients.inMemory()
    .withClient(“appAClientID”)
    .secret(“appAClientSecret”)
    .resourceIds(“APPA_RESOURCE_ID”)
    .authorizedGrantTypes(“password”, “refresh_token”) 
        .authorities(“ROLE_CLIENT”, “ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT”)
        .scopes(“read”, “write”)
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(600)        
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
         //End: Add App-A Protected Resources       
}
}
```

My Resource Server Configuration on OAuth2 Provider

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class SMEEShopResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    /**
     * Allow only authenticated requests
     * to access /user
     */
    http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/user/**")
    .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated();

    /**
     * Resource Configuration for App-A
     */

    http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/appA/xyz/**")
    .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/appA/xyz/**").permitALl();

    http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/appA/123/**")
    .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/appA/123/**").authenticated();

    /**
     * Add CSRF Filter
     */
       http.authorizeRequests().and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
    .and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String RESOURCE_ID = “APPA_RESOURCE_ID”;
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).tokenServices(getRemoteTokenService()); 
}
}
        private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                    .getName());
             if (csrf != null) {
                Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                String token = csrf.getToken();
                if (cookie == null || token != null
                        && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                    cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    };
}

protected CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}

@Override
@Primary
@Bean
public RemoteTokenServices getRemoteTokenService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
    tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(“http://localhost:8080/oauth/check_token”);
    tokenService.setClientId(“appAClientID”);
tokenService.setClientSecret(“appAClientSecret”);
    return tokenService;
}
```

And the Resource Server on App A

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends   ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/**").and()
    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
    .and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}
  @Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String RESOURCE_ID = “APPA_RESOURCE_ID”;
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).tokenServices(getRemoteTokenService()); 
}
}
protected Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
    return new OncePerRequestFilter() {

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                    .getName());
             if (csrf != null) {
                Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                String token = csrf.getToken();
                if (cookie == null || token != null
                        && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                    cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    };
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}

@Override
@Primary
@Bean
public RemoteTokenServices getRemoteTokenService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
    tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(“http://localhost:8080/oauth/check_token”);
    tokenService.setClientId(“appAClientID”);
tokenService.setClientSecret(“appAClientSecret”);
    return tokenService;
}
```

My application.properties of App-A

```
server.port=8090
server.context-path=/appA

# ----------------------------------------
# oAUTH 2.0 PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------
security.oauth2.client.client-id= appAClientID
security.oauth2.client.client-secret= appAClientSecret
spring.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
security.oauth2.resource.id=APPA_RESOURCE_ID
security.oauth2.resource.token-info- uri=http://localhost:8080/oauth/check_token
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri= http://localhost:8080/user
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please help me out on this? This is quite important and needs to be resolved immediately